# Uninstall hook/event for vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I don't see in the vscode documentation anything about a "uninstall hook". Basically I have an extension that needs to do some cleanup on the system's file system when uninstalling but *not* if simply deactivating. (shutting down vscode).

Comment: FYI: there is an active issue on this. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/35006

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This hook was added this year in vs code version 1.21: [Extension uninstall hook](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_21#_extension-uninstall-hook)

> If your extension has some clean ups to be done when it is uninstalled
>   from VS Code, you can now do that by registering a node script to the
>   uninstall hook `vscode:uninstall` under scripts section in extension's
>   `package.json`.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "vscode:uninstall": "node ./out/src/lifecycle"
  }
}
```

> This script gets executed when the extension is completely uninstalled
>   from VS Code which is when VS Code is restarted (shutdown and start)
>   after the extension is uninstalled.

Comment: Yeah, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49205613/how-to-execute-code-when-user-uninstalls-your-vscode-extension/49211345#49211345