# How to execute code when user uninstalls your VSCode Extension?

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

I read the entire visual studio code extensibility documentation and didn't find something like that. I wanna do a clean up, not when extension is deactivated but when it is uninstalled. I also try using the "uninstall" and "postUninstall" scripts fields from package.json but it didn't execute the scripts. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was just added in v1.21:  [Extension uninstall hook](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_21#_extension-uninstall-hook)

> If your extension has some clean ups to be done when it is uninstalled from VS Code, you can now do that by registering a node script to the uninstall hook vscode:uninstall under scripts section in extension's package.json.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "vscode:uninstall": "node ./out/src/lifecycle"
  }
}
```

> This script gets executed when the extension is completely uninstalled from VS Code which is when VS Code is restarted (shutdown and start) after the extension is uninstalled.
>
> **Note**: Only Node.js scripts are supported.

Comment: This is great news!! Wow, just in time for me. I was about to add a feature request on GitHub.

Comment: Hi Mark! I have a vscode extension, how can I exclude certain  files and folder from extension? `.gitignore` didn't work

Comment: @Nur If you mean so that those files are not part of the packaged/published extension, there should have been a `.vscodeignore` file automatically generated by the `yo code` generator.  It uses the same syntax as `.gitignore`.